# Trigger.io Android plugin: onStart not being triggered on ForgeEventListener

Tags: android, trigger.io

I'm trying to run some plugin initialisation code on the onStart() event but it's not being called when run from my application.

For example, the following doesn't run:

```
public class EventListener extends ForgeEventListener implements PluginClient {
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    // Some init code here
    logOutput("Plugin initialized");

}
```

Curiously the event runs ok on ForgeInspector as we can see on LogCat:

```
07-03 16:26:00.622: D/Forge(25867): Returned: {"event":"inspector.eventInvoked","params":{"name":"onStart","class":"io.trigger.forge.android.modules.myplugin.EventListener"}}
07-03 16:26:01.052: D/SNP(25867): Plugin initialized
```

Am i missing something or do i need to invoke it from JS side?

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that the onStart() IS being called, but something goes wrong on my plugin init code that it doesn't run. I'm having a hard time debugging it on App/outside Inspector.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've managed to debug the problem and it turns out that a piece of code inside a lib i'm using is causing the problem:

```
localProperties.load(mySDK.class.getResourceAsStream("/sdk.properties"));
```

Again, it reads ok the sdk.properties on Inspector but on my app it throw this error:

```
07-12 11:01:39.736: D/SNP(10848): java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
07-12 11:01:39.736: D/SNP(10848):     java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Got it! The problem is with Trigger.IO not including a SDK properties file on the final build. Any way to work around that?

Thanks!

Comment: So the plugin's event handlers work OK in the Inspector project, but don't execute when used in the app? Have you set the app to use the right version of your uploaded plugin? If you add methods to your plugin's `API.java`, can you invoke them from JS?

Comment: @JamesBrady plugin version always current and the API.java works great in this and other plugins. The code on onStart() and onCreate() don't execute in the app or maybe is being executed in another thread?(but i don't see any log message). Oddly the onResume() works ok in both scenarios(Inspector and App). As I am not an experienced Android/Java developer, maybe I'm doing something very stupid, but the different operation between Inspector and my App is puzzling me.

Comment: All working OK for me here... can you share source with us at support@trigger.io?